# How to remove and add image from/to intArrayOf?

Tags: android, arrays, image, kotlin

What code should I use if I want to remove or add image to/from array like:

```
var cats = intArrayOf(
                        R.drawable.cat__3_,
                        R.drawable.cat__4_,
                        R.drawable.cat__5_,
                        R.drawable.cat__6_,
                        R.drawable.cat__7_,
                        R.drawable.cat__8_)
```

For example: remove `cat__7_` and add `cat__7_` and `cat __9_`?

Comment: Just to be clear, your array is not holding the actual images, but rather their resource ids which could then be used to load the actual images.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Arrays](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-array/index.html) do not have methods to add/remove elements. You can try using [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html#kotlin.collections.MutableList) which can be created with [mutableListOf()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/mutable-list-of.html).